# How to align an object relative to nodes of another object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, alignment

I'd like to align one object to the *nodes* of another object. In the screenshot below, I'd like to horizontally align the text below to the axis marker that's represented by the two selected nodes above.

[image: Part of an X axis and a manual label]

I could duplicate the axis, select all nodes that don't belong to that small vertical line, delete them, do the alignment and then delete the temporary object. But since I didn't even find a way to invert the selection of nodes, this process is very laborious and error-prone. So any better way to do this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I would do in this case is the following:

1. Select the two nodes relevant for alignment

   [image]
2. Choose *Path > Break apart* to generate a separate object from the vertical line.
3. Select first the text, then the vertical line

   [image]
4. Now open *Object > Align and distribute* with setting **Relative to <kbd>Last selected</kbd>**

   [image]
5. Align the objects according to needs:

   - To align the left of the text choose *Align left edge to right edge of anchor:* [image]

     [image]
   - To center choose *Center on vertical axis:* [image]

     [image]
6. Now select the horizontal top line and the vertical line and choose *Path > Combine* to combine them to one object again.

Comment: "Break apart" was exactly the function I was searching for. That recombination step is optional for my case but it's good to know!

Comment: I am trying to do sort of the opposite, in the sense that I have an asymmetrical object that has a node that I want to align to another object. The node is not in the center of the object so the regular alignment functions do not work. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I'd :

- create another vertical segment
- center align it with the '1/4pi' text
- copy the "x" value of a node of this segment
- apply it to the two selected nodes.

Comment: Wouldn't that align the nodes to the object and not the other way around? But of course it's a good idea and easily adapted: just use the *x* value of the nodes, copy them to the vertical segment and use it to align the text.